# GetStringAsync method not responding

Tags: json, web-services, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get some custom columns values (longitude,latitude) from ASPNetUsers Table from the DB , When I send a Get request throw browser I get a 200 ok with the requested json .. but when I try to use GetStringAsync to deserialize the response in my xamarin app I don't get any response .

In AccountController class

```
// POST api/Account/GetUserPostion
    [Route("GetUserPostion")]

    public LocationDataToPostAsync GetUserPostion()
    {
        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
        LocationDataToPostAsync locationData = new LocationDataToPostAsync();


        var model = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        locationData.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (model.Longitude != null) locationData.Longitude = (double) model.Longitude;
        if (model.Latitude != null) locationData.Latitude = (double) model.Latitude;

        return locationData;



    }
```

In ApiService class in xamarin forms app

```
public async Task<LocationDataToPostAsync> GetUserLocationAsync(string accessToken)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://10.0.2.2:45455/api/Account/GetUserPostion");

        var location = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocationDataToPostAsync>(json);

        return location;

    }
```

Comment: Where and how do you call `GetUserLocationAsync`? Is any exception thrown or does execution just stop? In latter case it sounds like a dead-lock and indicates you are calling the method incorrectly.

Comment: In a class called MapPageViewModel       public async Task<LocationDataToPostAsync> GetUserLocation()
        {
            var accesstoken = Settings.AccessToken;
            UserCurrentLocation = await _apiServices.GetUserLocationAsync(accesstoken);
            return UserCurrentLocation;
        }

Comment: The execution doesn't go beyond the await in getstringasync .. there is no exception thrown ... probably there is a problem with the call .. but at least isn't the json var should return something ?! because like I said when I call It from the browser the response is 200 ok along with the requested data ?!

Comment: The topmost level where you call the async method, how is that done? Are you calling `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the task, or what are you doing? Anyways, try add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere where you `await` a Task unless you specifically need to return to the context you came from.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron .. I added .ConfigureAwait(false) to the await call and it's work now ..

Comment: Do you know why it works?

Comment: Will I came across this article medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f

Comment: Yes, but do YOU understand it? Just linking to a random article doesn't automatically mean you understand :)

Comment: What I get from the article is that the UI thread is blocked and I think it's because the method I called from it is the problem which is not implement await in GetUserLocation call  >>  public void LocationMethod()
     {
         MapPageViewModel model = new MapPageViewModel();
         Task<LocationDataToPostAsync> userLocation = model.GetUserLocation();

            var result = userLocation.Result;
         var position1 = new Position(result.Latitude, result.Longitude);

Comment: The problem is that you call `.Result` on your tasks.

Comment: So when I use .Result the execution will never end and the UI will freeze ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear from your code if the `Task` is awaited or you are calling `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the `Task`. However, as we found out in the comments adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` fixed your issue.

This indicates that the code cannot return to the context it came from, so adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` the code doesn't return to the context.

In your case the context is probably the UI thread and when it tries to return the UI thread is blocked.

The most likely scenario why the UI Thread is block is because you called your Task in a wrong manner. If you call it with `.Result` on the UI thread you are synchronously blocking the UI thread, hence anything that tries to return to the UI thread, will deadlock, since you are blocking that.

The easy fix here is to just add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in your code. The better solution would be not to block the UI thread by awaiting the Task.